# Change Razer mechanical keyboard to qwertz?

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible to change the Razer mechanical keyboard from azerty to qwertz layout? I have seen the key cups get off very easily can you just change the key cups and it gives me qwertz layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the alphanumeric keys, if they come off easily without breaking them ofcourse. You might need different key caps for the special keys to fit the qwertz layout. Don't forget to change the input method in your OS.

Comment: @Thandruill:I forgot the special keys. Maybe its not so good idea. Thanks!